# how to print only 1st argument in two arguments function?

Tags: python, file

I have a txt.file and string input as an arguments, given string input my function will print corresponding line/string from the file in a set. And file has one word per line.

```
def angram(s1,s2):
    st = set()
    if sorted(s1) == sorted(s2):
       st.add(s1)
  return st
angram('my.txt', 'top')
```

```
expected output: {'pot'}
```

```
but output I get {'pot','top'}
```

I do not want the string input in set. I want only output result from file.
Any way to do that??

Comment: That code, after fixing the indentation error, should return an empty set. Also, I do not understand the wnated behaviour at all. Is it _"print only the first argument"_ or print `{'pot','top'}`, which has nothing to do with the first argument? And where do you read a file?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I read, opened file at the beginning, but I am stuck at the end, yes print only the first argument which is a text file. so I want it to print only ```{ 'pot"}``` the anagram of given string 'top'

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Python builtin functions for reading files.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/

Given:

```
car
pto
pot
```

Output:

```
{'pot', 'pto'}
```

Code:

```
def anagram(s1,s2):
    st = set()
    fh = open('my.txt')
    target = sorted(s2)
    while True:
        line = fh.readline()      # while there is line to read in the file
        check = line.strip('\n')  # some lines will include "\n" in index 0 - remove it
        if sorted(check) == target:
          st.add(check)
        if not line:
            break
    fh.close()
    st.remove(s2) # the user doesn't want the same word as the target (s2) to be included
    return st
anagram('my.txt', 'top')
```

Comment: it also gives ```{ 'pot', 'top'}``` , but I only want ```{ 'pot' }``` :(

Comment: @jay.andrea I have updated the code to remove if s2 exists.